# Arithmetic Expressions as argument to macro in c

Tags: c

using macro with preprocessor directive #define I have written the following two codes.

- first code passes the expression e.g. a+b

> _valid_pagesize(a+b)

- in second code

> c=a+b

and then passed this c as an argument to macro.

> _valid_pagesize(c)

the second code runs perfectly whereas the first code doesn't.
can we not pass expressions as arguments to macro like the way we can in case of a function..?
why not..?

the code passing expression as argument :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define _valid_pagesize(_newsize) (!(_newsize % 0x80000000)?1:      \
        (!(_newsize % 0x40000000)?1:      \
        (!(_newsize % 0x10000000)?1:      \
        (!(_newsize % 0x4000000) ?1:0))))


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    uint64_t size[2];
    size[0]=atoi(argv[1]);
    size[1]=atoi(argv[2]);

    if(_valid_pagesize(size[0]+size[1])){
            printf("success\n");
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule #1 with macros is to enclose all arguments in parentheses, to avoid exactly the problem that you're seeing.

```
#define _valid_pagesize(_newsize) (!((_newsize) % 0x80000000)?1:      \
    (!((_newsize) % 0x40000000)?1:      \
    (!((_newsize) % 0x10000000)?1:      \
    (!((_newsize) % 0x4000000) ?1:0))))
```

When you pass `a+b` to the macro, it expands to

```
a + b % 0x40000000
```

and since `%` has higher precedence than `+`, you don't get the result you expect. By enclosing the argument in parentheses, the macro expands to

```
(a + b) % 0x40000000
```

which works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Macro parameters aren't evaluated prior to being passed to the macro, since macro expansion occurs prior to compilation. Instead, the actual expression is passed unchanged into the macro, and is substituted into all occurrences of the parameter name. Therefore, `_valid_pagesize(a+b)` expands to this:

```
(!(a+b % 0x80000000)?1:      \
    (!(a+b % 0x40000000)?1:      \
    (!(a+b % 0x10000000)?1:      \
    (!(a+b % 0x4000000) ?1:0))))
```

Now, the reason it produces wrong answers is hopefully obvious. Follow user3386109's advice about enclosing the parameter in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Put _newsize inside braces in the macro expansion

Comment: _valid_pagesize((size[0]+size[1]))- original -> incorrect output
**(**_valid_pagesize**)**((size[0]+size[1]))-  your suggestion-> compilation error
_valid_pagesize**(**((size[0]+size[1]))**)**- works :)